# How to solve com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity Class not found exception in razorpay after merging my projects ? Before merging it was working fine

Tags: java, android

I just merged two apps A & B into one by importing the B as library module. The App A has Razorpay integration. Before merging the apps razorpay was working fine but after merging it shows com.razorpay.checkout activity not found exception.

I used proguard rule by enabling it from the gradle. Also  I upgraded the razorpay library version to 1.5.5. But Still not working.

```
public void startPayment() {
        /*
          You need to pass current activity in order to let Razorpay create CheckoutActivity
         */
        /*
          You need to pass current activity in order to let Razorpay create CheckoutActivity
         */
            final Checkout co = new Checkout();
            co.setImage(R.drawable.kdgologo);

        final Activity activity = this;


        int amount= Integer.parseInt(amountget);

        try {
            JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
            options.put("name", customer_idget);
            options.put("description", orderIdget);
            //You can omit the image option to fetch the image from dashboard
            options.put("image", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rzp-mobile/images/rzp.png");
            options.put("currency", "INR");
            options.put("amount", amount*100);

            JSONObject preFill = new JSONObject();
            preFill.put("email", emailget);
            preFill.put("contact", cnumberget);

            options.put("prefill", preFill);

            JSONObject notes = new JSONObject();
            notes.put("opencart_order_id", orderIdget);
            options.put("notes",notes);

            co.open(activity, options);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error in payment: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Error message:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.kdgo.in/com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1618)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:4392)
at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1100)
at android.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1084)
at com.razorpay.Checkout.onCreate(:302)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: Check the resulted menifest file. Is there everything merged properly.

Comment: I think so as everything is working fine other than razorpay issue.

Comment: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml`??

Comment: It's a razorpay Activity(com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity)(using Razorpay library)  , I think it can't be declared in our manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

> I just merged two apps A & B into one by importing the B as library module. The App A has Razorpay integration. Before merging the apps razorpay was working fine but after merging it shows com.razorpay.checkout activity not found exception

The main problem when integrating a project as module is that forgetting to  include the library to the main app `module`. That's mainly because we're using `implementation` for the dependencies.

You can change the dependencies in the library module from `implementation` to `api`. Or alternatively, you can copy the dependencies line to your main app module.

Comment: using "api project(path: ':app2')" in the main app gradle didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, thanks to @android killer. i just checked my Manifest files. I had added **tool:replace in the  tag. I removed it** and removed the android:icon &  android:roundIcon from the other manifest file so that tool:replace must not be needed. And It works fine now.